# Opening Firefox searches in a tab and backgrounding the new tab

Tags: macos, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser-tabs

In Chrome, when typing a search into the Omnibar, I can user <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the webpage or search query in a new tab, with the tab immediately being backgrounded -- this way, my focus stays on the current page rater than switching tabs.

In Firefox, I can use the similar key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open a search or URL in a new tab, but the new tab is immediately focused.

Is there a key combination in Firefox that lets me mimic the backgrounding behaviour present in Chrome? Additionally, is there any way I can bind this to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>?

My operating system is OS X.

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there a shortcut in Firefox that lets me mimic the  behaviour present in Chrome?

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> will open the search results in a new tab, but leave the focus on the current tab.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Firefox 47.0.1 under OS X. I also tried using Cmd instead of control -- that doesn't work either.

Comment: @Jules Then perhaps you should edit your question to include your OS. It works on Windows as per my answer.

Comment: edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Answered a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1332374/is-there-a-way-to-open-up-a-url-in-a-background-tab-in-firefox)

In both Windows and Mac OS, you can open a new tab from the address bar in the background with ALT-CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER. This is probably a [defect](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1506203)