# Is there a way to open up a URL in a background tab in Firefox?

Tags: macos, firefox

Is there a way to type URL in location bar of current tab and press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to open this URL in background tab, like in Chrome and Safari?

Comment: Do you want to ALWAYS send new tabs to the background, or do you want to be able to choose between with one of the choices being default?

Comment: I want be able to press cmd/ctrl/whatever modifier key + enter to open url I typed in location bar in a new background tab.

Comment: Does TabMixPlus work in Firefox on MacOS?

Comment: Not compatible with Firefox QuantumNot compatible with Firefox Quantum

Answer (score 2):

Type <kbd>⌥ (Option)</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> to open a URL from the address bar in a new tab in Firefox within macOS.

Comment: It opens in new tab but not new background tab

Answer (score 2):

In Windows... Rather than <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, you could <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click on the first item that shows up (in my case - whatever I typed in the search bar - *Search with Google* for search items or ... - *Visit* for URLs) for it to open in a new foreground tab, or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+click for it to open in a background tab. I don't have a Mac to test on, but there should be an equivalent so maybe play around with keys and clicks until you figure it out?

Comment: You can also Ctrl+Shift+Left-Click the "Go" button (which nowadays appears as an arrow pointing to the right at the far right of the address bar: → )

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, but for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click to link it works, if you in

**Options, General, Tabs**

*uncheck* the option for bringing the tab with new opened URL into foreground.

Comment: Didn't help. Pressing cmd+enter does not open url I typed in location bar in a new background tab.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. It works only with Ctrl+click to link.

Answer (score 1):

ALT-CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER will open a URL from the address bar in a new background tab.

see: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1506203